# Cannot install my android app on genymotion device

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, genymotion

I started to test genymotion, for that i installed the genymotion plugin for eclipse. I am able to start the device from inside eclipse but I cannot install my android application on the device. I tried it like this:

1. Run-as--> Android Applicaitomn
2. Choosing my device which has been started in genymotion

The Console-Output is

```
    [2014-04-25 11:03:20 - PDiXUploader] ------------------------------
    [2014-04-25 11:03:20 - PDiXUploader] Android Launch!
    [2014-04-25 11:03:20 - PDiXUploader] adb is running normally.
    [2014-04-25 11:03:20 - PDiXUploader] Performing de.srs.android.pdixuploader.activies.LoginActivity activity launch
    [2014-04-25 11:03:26 - PDiXUploader] Uploading PDiXUploader.apk onto device '192.168.56.101:5555'
    [2014-04-25 11:03:26 - PDiXUploader] Installing PDiXUploader.apk...
    [2014-04-25 11:03:26 - PDiXUploader] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR
    [2014-04-25 11:03:26 - PDiXUploader] Please check logcat output for more details.
    [2014-04-25 11:03:26 - PDiXUploader] Launch canceled!
```

The logcat has this output

```
04-25 09:03:23.810: D/AndroidRuntime(1445): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-25 09:03:23.810: D/AndroidRuntime(1445): CheckJNI is OFF
04-25 09:03:23.830: D/AndroidRuntime(1445): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
04-25 09:03:23.842: I/ActivityManager(1100): Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=1452 uid=10017 gids={1015, 2001}
04-25 09:03:23.861: D/dalvikvm(1452): GC_EXPLICIT freed 284K, 52% free 2687K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 3ms
04-25 09:03:23.910: W/ActivityManager(1100): No content provider found for: 
04-25 09:03:23.910: D/VoldCmdListener(1036): asec list
04-25 09:03:23.910: I/PackageHelper(1452): Size of container 3 MB 1654823 bytes
04-25 09:03:23.910: D/VoldCmdListener(1036): asec create smdl2tmp1 3 fat {} 10017
04-25 09:03:23.910: E/Vold(1036): Error creating imagefile (Read-only file system)
04-25 09:03:23.910: E/Vold(1036): ASEC image file creation failed (Read-only file system)
04-25 09:03:23.910: W/Vold(1036): Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 30
04-25 09:03:23.910: E/PackageHelper(1452): Failed to create secure container smdl2tmp1
04-25 09:03:23.910: E/DefContainer(1452): Failed to create container smdl2tmp1
04-25 09:03:23.910: W/ActivityManager(1100): No content provider found for: 
04-25 09:03:23.920: D/dalvikvm(1100): GC_EXPLICIT freed 867K, 46% free 4074K/7495K, external 4378K/5578K, paused 6ms
04-25 09:03:23.920: D/AndroidRuntime(1445): Shutting down VM
04-25 09:03:23.930: D/dalvikvm(1445): GC_CONCURRENT freed 209K, 71% free 299K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 0ms+0ms
04-25 09:03:23.930: D/jdwp(1445): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
04-25 09:03:23.930: D/dalvikvm(1445): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-25 09:03:27.740: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:03:28.095: D/Genyd(1100): Received Set Clipboard
04-25 09:03:28.095: D/Genymotion(1100): Received Set Clipboard
04-25 09:03:28.095: D/GenydService(1100): Set clipboard
04-25 09:03:32.742: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:03:37.740: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:03:38.923: D/Genyd(1100): Received Set Clipboard
04-25 09:03:38.923: D/Genymotion(1100): Received Set Clipboard
04-25 09:03:38.923: D/GenydService(1100): Set clipboard
04-25 09:03:42.740: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:03:47.750: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:03:52.750: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:03:53.420: D/Genyd(1100): Received Set Clipboard
04-25 09:03:53.420: D/Genymotion(1100): Received Set Clipboard
04-25 09:03:53.420: D/GenydService(1100): Set clipboard
04-25 09:03:57.753: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:04:02.753: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:04:07.754: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:04:12.750: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:04:17.755: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:04:21.189: D/Genyd(1100): Received Set Clipboard
04-25 09:04:21.189: D/Genymotion(1100): Received Set Clipboard
04-25 09:04:21.190: D/GenydService(1100): Set clipboard
04-25 09:04:22.756: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:04:27.758: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:04:32.760: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:04:37.040: D/Genyd(1100): Received Set Clipboard
04-25 09:04:37.040: D/Genymotion(1100): Received Set Clipboard
04-25 09:04:37.040: D/GenydService(1100): Set clipboard
04-25 09:04:37.760: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:04:42.761: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
04-25 09:04:47.763: E/Genymotion(1100): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
```

Anyone an idea what might be te problem?

Comment: I think this is offtopic here. Try the support department of Genymotion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have something like this in your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

I had the same error and removing this helped me.

Try to remove this for install the app on genymotion.